# Creating service to monitor and read contents of file from a folder

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am trying to create a service that will try to create a service that will monitor a folder. Whenever a new file gets created, I am trying to read the contents of new file and copy contents (with same file)  at a new location.

The problem I am facing is that only first file that gets its name copied and a file created at a new location, but without any contents. The subsequent files do not get created at all.

My Services.cs looks like this:-

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        Watcher.Path = "C:\\logs\\";
        Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Changed);
        Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private static void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        var CopyContents = new Thread(() => ThreadProcedure(e));
        CopyContents.IsBackground = true;
        CopyContents.Start();

    }

    private static void ThreadProcedure(FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(e.FullPath);
        string testfilepath = "C:\\Project Tests\\testfile\\" + e.Name;
        File.Create(testfilepath);
        var log = new StreamWriter(testfilepath);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            log.WriteLine(line);
            counter++;
        }
        log.Close();
        file.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: From memory the created event will get fired the moment the file is created on the disk, not necessarily after its content has been written to it. I seem to remember the solution I used in the past was to just wait a little while before processing the files. Though there might be a better solution than I used many years ago... :)

Comment: Is there a reason you use StreamReader/StreamWriter to copy the file, instead of `System.IO.File.Copy`?

Comment: I tried to put Thread.Sleep(10000) at the start of threading function but it did not work.

Comment: I am using StreamReader because in the future I am going to continuously tail each line of log,currently just testing the basics :)

Comment: I think this was some kind of bug in the streamwriter method of C#
We had a project in which XML files randomly got cleared, after we rewrote our paser it was solved, note reading was just fine.